# Select value of specific membership profile property using SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Even though this should be a common question, I haven't found much about it in Google.
I am using ASP.NET membership, and saving all users properties in PropertyValuesString field in aspnet_Profile table.

Now I want to search users by a specific property value, but using an SQL query. What is the best performance wise approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asp_profile stuff is such a string concatenation hack-job that this is very difficult.

But here ya go.

http://www.karpach.com/Get-asp-net-profile-value-MS-SQL-database-using-T-SQL.htm

I'll paste the code here to avoid a dead-link issue.  BUT check out the link as well, because there are comments that are worth the read.

```
ASP.Net profiles can store binary data as well, but usually your are interested in string data such as First and Last names. First lets create helper function, which helps to get position:length pair values:

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetElement

(

@ord AS INT,

@str AS VARCHAR(8000),

@delim AS VARCHAR(1) )



RETURNS INT

AS

BEGIN

  -- If input is invalid, return null.

  IF @str IS NULL

      OR LEN(@str) = 0

      OR @ord IS NULL

      OR @ord < 1

      -- @ord > [is the] expression that calculates the number of elements.

      OR @ord > LEN(@str) - LEN(REPLACE(@str, @delim, '')) + 1

    RETURN NULL

  DECLARE @pos AS INT, @curord AS INT

  SELECT @pos = 1, @curord = 1

  -- Find next element's start position and increment index.

  WHILE @curord < @ord

    SELECT

      @pos    = CHARINDEX(@delim, @str, @pos) + 1,

      @curord = @curord + 1

  RETURN

  CAST(SUBSTRING(@str, @pos, CHARINDEX(@delim, @str + @delim, @pos) - @pos) AS INT)

END



And then code for the actual worker function:

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetProfileElement

(

@fieldName AS NVARCHAR(100),

@fields AS NVARCHAR(4000),

@values AS NVARCHAR(4000))



RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)

AS

BEGIN

  -- If input is invalid, return null.

  IF @fieldName IS NULL

      OR LEN(@fieldName) = 0

      OR @fields IS NULL

      OR LEN(@fields) = 0

      OR @values IS NULL

      OR LEN(@values) = 0



    RETURN NULL



-- locate FieldName in Fields

DECLARE @fieldNameToken AS NVARCHAR(20)

DECLARE @fieldNameStart AS INTEGER,

@valueStart AS INTEGER,

@valueLength AS INTEGER



-- Only handle string type fields (:S:)

SET @fieldNameStart = CHARINDEX(@fieldName + ':S',@Fields,0)



-- If field is not found, return null

IF @fieldNameStart = 0 RETURN NULL

SET @fieldNameStart = @fieldNameStart + LEN(@fieldName) + 3



-- Get the field token which I've defined as the start of the

-- field offset to the end of the length

SET @fieldNameToken = SUBSTRING(@Fields,@fieldNameStart,LEN(@Fields)-@fieldNameStart)



-- Get the values for the offset and length

SET @valueStart = dbo.fn_getelement(1,@fieldNameToken,':')

SET @valueLength = dbo.fn_getelement(2,@fieldNameToken,':')



-- Check for sane values, 0 length means the profile item was

-- stored, just no data

IF @valueLength = 0 RETURN ''



-- Return the string

RETURN SUBSTRING(@values, @valueStart+1, @valueLength)



END



Now we can get first name and last name as following:



SELECT dbo.fn_GetProfileElement('FirstName',PropertyNames,PropertyValuesString) + ' ' +



dbo.fn_GetProfileElement('LastName',PropertyNames,PropertyValuesString) as FullName FROM aspnet_Profile
```

Comment: Ooops, may be a repeat question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315284/sql-aspnet-profile

Comment: Thank you very much! that solved the problem. As for the other question, unfortunately the title does not tell much about the question no the answer.